# How can I get the "&format=txt" mediawiki api option back?

Tags: text, format, mediawiki, deprecated, mediawiki-api

My program relies on an API option in Media wiki

[image]

After reinstalling mediawiki on Ubuntu 16.10, the option no longer exists:

[image]

Because of this:

[image]

How can I get this option back?

Comment: Can you use the obvious solution, that is, installing an older version of MediaWiki (presumably, 1.26)?

Comment: @svick Of course; if it is easy, and error free. I ended up just using JSON format and correcting my program, so at this moment, I'll accept any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could grap the `ApiFormatTxt` class form 1.26, update it for any changes since and add it to your MediaWiki installation. Of course, rewriting your code to use JSON takes much less time and makes it more robust.